# Script method for clearing Silverlight Application Storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight, firefox, mozilla

i wonder whither exists or not, a script based method such in Javascript for clearing silverlight application storage on browsers.
am aware it's done manually by clicking the flash player on the webpage -> silverlight -> appstorage -> delete all.
i also found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423088/programmatically-clear-silverlight-application-storage) but it's for c#
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no plugin for that purpose. 
you can set silverlight activation to "ask" to avoid collecting those data by other sites. 
i think those data are sandboxed but i am not sure at 100%
have a loot at 
[Programmatically clear Silverlight Application Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423088/programmatically-clear-silverlight-application-storage)